# Mongoid unique model references

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

I'm using Mongoid 3. I have a simple class `Tour` and references multiple `Itineraries`. Is there a way that I can validate that for each tour, the itineraries' dates are unique, i.e. I can't have 2 itineraries of the same date for a single tour.

```
class Tour
  has_many :itineraries
end

class Itinerary
  field :date, :type => Date
  validates :date, :presence => true
  index({date: 1})

  belongs_to :tour
end
```

I'm not sure how to set up the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom validations :

```
class Tour
  has_many :itineraries
  validates :check_uniqueness_of_date # This line

  # And this part
  private 
  def check_uniqueness_of_date
    # Check validation here
  end
end
```

[Another Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533546/rails-custom-validation)

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations)