# Rails 3.2 Validate based on different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How would I make this work?  I want to validate an award nomination based on criteria from a different model.

```
      class Award < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => 'Manager', :foreign_key => 'manager_username'



  def cant_be_manager
     if nominee_username == Manager.username   
       errors.add(:nominee, "is a manager and cannot be nominated.")
     end
  end

end
```

Comment: I think that you want to use lowercase `manager.username` as well

Comment: I'm so sorry.  I will try to put the original post back the way it was, accept your answer, then ask the "new" question separately.  I was trying to only provide pertinent information and didn't explain myself completely. My apologies.

Comment: No problem.  However, I'm not sure I completely answered your original question, and I'm still willing to.  If you figured it out with what I gave you, that's fine, but if you need any more help, just answer the questions I asked below, and I will update with a more complete answer.

Comment: I will open a new question today, since I convoluted this one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'manager_username'

  validate :cant_be_manager  # <----- added this line

  def cant_be_manager
     if nominee_username == manager.username    # <----- lower case m
       errors.add(:nominee, "is a manager and cannot be nominated.")
     end
  end

end
```

But (just guessing here what your model looks like) I'm wondering if that second modified line shouldn't be:

```
if nominee_username == manager_username
```

The belongs_to line indicates that you have a manager_username field in your awards table, but it would be more common in Rails for this to be a manager_id field, with the belongs_to line looking like this:

```
belongs_to :manager, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'manager_id'
```

If that is indeed what you have, your code should look like this:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'manager_id'  # <----- changed

  validate :cant_be_manager  # <----- added this line

  def cant_be_manager
     if nominee_id == manager_id    # <----- changed
       errors.add(:nominee, "is a manager and cannot be nominated.")
     end
  end

end
```

This assumes that you are trying to prevent an employee from nominating his own manager, but it's okay for the employee to nominate other managers, or for managers to nominate other managers.  If instead you want to prevent any managers at all from being nominated by anyone, let me know how you know if an Employee is a manager (probably an attribute or method on your Employee model) and I will update the answer.

Comment: I did already have `validate :cant_be_manager` ---  I get this: `undefined method username for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @KatieM, can you tell me exactly what fields are on your Award model and Employee model?  Specifically, is it manager_username or manager_id, and for the Employee model, how do you know if an Employee is a manager?

Comment: My bad - for brevity, I didn't provide all the info.  I updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe smth. like this?

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :cant_be_manager

  def cant_be_manager
  .....
end
```

See this question too: [Rails custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533546/rails-custom-validation)