# rails combine duplicate validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

i am developing rails 3 and have multiple validation for same name. i want to combine duplicate validation with conditional. I don't know if i'm doing it wrong or it even possible.

**in my model (original)**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :exchange_rate, :presence     => true,
                             :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 },
                             :unless       => :is_using_default_currency?
   validates :exchange_rate, :numericality => { :equal_to => 1 },
                             :if           => :is_using_default_currency?
private

   def is_using_default_currency?
     value == 1   
   end
end
```

i want to do something like this

**in my model**

```
validates :exchange_rate, :presence => true, :exchange_rate => true
```

**in custom validator class**

```
class ExchangeRateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator 

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    @record = record
    if is_using_default_currency?
      validates :exchange_rate, :presence     => true,
                                :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }    
    else
      validates :exchange_rate, :numericality => { :equal_to => 1 }
    end
  end 
private
  def is_using_default_currency?
    @record.value == 1
  end
end
```

is that possible? or is there any better ways to combine validations to make code DRY?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with custom validation methods:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations
[Rails custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533546/rails-custom-validation)

Comment: thanks for the asnwer Ganesh, but i want to use default rails error message like :numericality. For now i use concern, it does what i want but not very good.

Comment: you can check for numericality in many condition within custom method. You can also custom error message within custom method.